# How do I ensure there are table rows, and iterate with Playwright

Tags: python, playwright-python

I am working on an automation script for a third-party website which manages credentials for a program. Within the script, I can successfully log into the website and place a search variable within the [Search] field and filter the results on the table within the website. However, I cannot figure out how to iterate over results that appear within the table. The data that returns within rows appears to be a dump of the entire table, not just the filtered results which are represented in the browser.

I'm attempting to come up with the following:

1. If there are no matches, exit function
2. If there is at least 1 match, iterate over the rows and load the [Key Name] value into a variable

I have reviewed the [locators](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators) documentation from Playwright, but the Lists section does not appear to work correctly with the code I have.

```
def deactivate_current_license(page, email_address):
    print(f"Searching for currently assigned licenses for {email_address}")
    
    page.locator('text=Search: >> input[type="search"]').fill(email_address)
    page.locator('text=Search: >> input[type="search"]').press("Enter")

    # Locate elements, this locator points to a list.
    rows = page.locator('table[id="tbl_Customer_Asset__c"]')

    # Pattern 3: resolve locator to elements on page and map them to their text content.
    # Note: the code inside evaluateAll runs in page, you can call any DOM apis there.
    texts = rows.evaluate_all("list => list.map(element => element.textContent)")
```

Here are images of how the table from the site appears with 3 different scenarios:
[image: No Matches]

[image: 1 Single Match]

[image: Multiple Matches]

Comment: Which site, please? It's hard to help without seeing the relevant HTML at least. Screenshots aren't really scrapable.

Comment: It's within the Tableau Customer Portal. Unfortunately, it's not something I can provide credentials to. It does seem to function similarly to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp.

Comment: OK, thanks--maybe try to reproduce it on a sample table like the one you're showing. I'm not going to bother writing an answer unless I'm sure it'll actually help solve your problem.

Comment: I have created a smaller test script for the w3schools link, and uploaded as a gist
https://gist.github.com/swolfe2/33e9c8b217c74156ae583e7780c1e879.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [snippet](https://gist.github.com/swolfe2/33e9c8b217c74156ae583e7780c1e879), there's a clear issue on the [w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp), which is that elements have a `style="display: none"` attribute set when they're not part of the search results. This hides them from the user's view but doesn't extract their text from the DOM. This is ignored by your scraping logic, which simply pulls all of the text contents regardless of whether it's in a hidden element or not.

In addition to the `:visible` pseudoselector, select the `tr` elements rather than the whole table. For example:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    url = "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp"
    page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")
    page.locator("#myInput").fill("t")
    page.locator("#myInput").press("Enter")
    table = (
        page.locator("#myTable tr:visible")
            .evaluate_all("""els => els.slice(1).map(el =>
              [...el.querySelectorAll('td')].map(e => e.textContent.trim())
            )""")
    )

    for row in table:
        print(row)

    browser.close()
```

Output:

```
['Alfreds Futterkiste', 'Germany']
['Island Trading', 'UK']
['Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti', 'Italy']
['North/South', 'UK']
['Paris specialites', 'France']
```

However, this might not extrapolate cleanly to your main problem. There are at least few other things that could be responsible for the failure on the other page.

There may be other visibility factors at play, so I would use the inspector to see whether those elements are being hidden, set to `display: none` (as with the w3schools example above), removed completely, or something else (like a width/height 0 hack--unlikely, but who knows) upon search.

The most likely scenario is that the search triggers an asynchronous HTTP request. You might need to wait for the table contents to change or the HTTP response to arrive before attempting to select the data from the DOM. You can verify this by looking at the network tab in the browser developer tools. Often, you can intercept the response and avoid messing with the DOM entirely. `wait_for_function` and `wait_for_response` can be useful here.

Although it's not recommended for the final script, setting a temporary timeout for a generous 5-10 seconds helps give the data a chance to arrive. Once you've detected the general behavior, you can then tighten the predicate with a specific function or repsonse and drop the timeout.

If this doesn't get you unstuck, I would try to create a simple page that captures the table behavior better than w3schools. You can mock API request delay with `setTimeout`. This might be tricky, but minimizing (isolating) the problem is usually 90% of debugging work.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply; I really appreciate it. I'm assuming that's also what's happening with the site I'm trying to read, where all of the rows actually still exist but are just being hidden with JS.